# Should we opt-out for Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion

To steal mercilessly from last year's post:

For those who are new to the Stack Exchange network, Winter Bash is an annual light-hearted event where users can earn virtual hats by doing certain things on an SE site within the Winter Bash time frame -- these hats that you earn can be worn as adornments on your SE avatar either on a particular site (e.g., Coffee) or network-wide (i.e., all of Stack Exchange).

The conditions for earning certain hats are "public" -- well-known to all; other hats are "secret" -- you need to figure out what to do to earn the hat. Some public hats might be... ask a well-received question, improve a question, submit an accepted edit, perform tasks in the review queue, etc. Some non-public hats in the past have been... contribute on a particular day, upvote and comment/improve on a first-question from a new user, etc.

Winter bash can be fun and users will sometimes get hats just by participating normally. Any user can opt-out of the Winter Bash (once it starts, any user can click a link like "no hats for me, thanks"); no hats will be earned nor viewed.

Once Winter Bash begins (19 December), stats can be viewed at http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/.

As a community, we can opt-out of Winterbash, but **we are opted in by default**. So, hats: yea or nay?

Answer (score 10):

No.

Comment: ... we should opt-in. Hats are great! Vote "NO" to say "YES" to hats...!

Comment: @hoc_age Yes. You've done that thing where you've phrased the yes/no option different ways around in the title/body :-P **THIS IS THE OPTION TO UPVOTE IF YOU WANT HATS**.

Comment: I was being pedantic; as he noted, @Nick borrowed the content from [my meta last year](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/are-we-in-for-winter-bash-2015) but he changed the sense of the question and thereby the answers; I asked "are we in." Nick's title is "should we opt-out" (negative-sense; opposite of mine) and the body says "hats: yea or nay?" (positive-sense) -- to my read, those are opposites... i.e., confusing and warranting clarification! You answered his *title* not his *body*. In good fun... and with hats... by voting "No..." to say "YES" to hats. :)